# Finding the p-value of a simple experiment in R?

Tags: p-value, binomial-distribution

I have 5 types of cards, and there are 5 cards of each type, leaving me with 25 cards. The hypothetical value that a subject will be able to predict the type of the card, assuming he predicts totally randomly, is 20%, or 5/25 cards.

Let's say a subject takes this test and is able to guess 10 of the cards. Now, being that the p-value is the probability that the subject is able to guess 10 or more cards, I would have thought that the p-value is simply

```
pbinom(25,25,0.2) - pbinom(10,25,0.2) = 1 - pbinom(10,25,0.2) = 0.00555492
```

This seems like a fine answer to me, however, I being asked to confirm my p-value using the `binom.test` function. I enter `binom.test(10, 25, p = 0.2)`, and here is where returns:

```
Exact binomial test

data:  10 and 25
number of successes = 10, number of trials = 25, p-value = 0.02111
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.2
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2112548 0.6133465
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                   0.4
```

What information here is supposed to give me insight on the p-value? What does the "probability of success" even entail here?

Comment: (1) Note that for any of your calculations to be relevant, this experiment must be conducted so that the 25 predictions are independent.  That means (at a minimum) that the subject was not informed of the results of any of the 25 predictions until all 25 were made and that cards were *replaced in the deck and shuffled* after each was pulled. (2) Please consult the software documentation: it states that the default test performed by `binom.test` is *two-sided* whereas the `pbinom` calculation is one-sided. The results better not agree!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your reply. The experiment itself is all hypothetical, so it's just assumed  that the procedure is done properly. However, I did not see that parameter for binom.test. That being said, I'm having trouble understanding the significance of knowing whether its two-tailed or not. Surely, if someone got 0/25, it would be suspicious. If someone got 15/25, it would be (even more) suspicious. So what is the use of specifiying what kind of alternative hypothesis it has, here? Thanks.

Comment: Because it changes the p-value.  Search our site for threads on two-sided (or two-tailed) tests for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference here between the probability of getting 10 or more cards correct given that you're choosing randomly, and the probability that you're choosing randomly given that you got 10 cards correct. The first probability value you calculated shows that it is very unlikely to get 10+ cards correct out of 25 if you are choosing randomly (with a 20% chance of being correct). The second probability from binom.test shows that it is very unlikely that you were actually choosing randomly with a 20% chance of being correct, given that you got 10/25 correct. The sample estimate is the data-based estimate of your chance of success, which is 40% (10/25). The binom.test is performing a hypothesis test, which tells you that the sample estimate is significantly different from your null hypothesis of random choice. Because the p-value is low, we can reject the null hypothesis that the true probability of success is equal to 0.2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So here the binom.test is suggesting that either I'm not choosing randomly or that my null hypothesis is wrong, and that it should in fact be around 0.4? Or is that a false interpretation? 

What sort of conclusion should I even be drawing from this? That its calculation of my probability of success is significantly higher that the one posed by my hypothesis, and therefore I should look over it? Furthermore, I don't understand what I can extrapolate about the p-value from this, that my low p-value seems to agree with the binome.test analysis? Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, as a side follow up question. If a person somehow manages to get 50% of the cards right, I can be sure that there's something wrong with my null? This is one of the things I'm confused about. At what point do I say that something is so unlikely that there's something wrong with my null? Surely, if someone gets a really high score, assuming they haven't cheated, then I know somethings wrong. But what if its not _that_ high, but still significantly above the average. What if it's only slightly above average? Where is the cutoff point, or is it arbitrary?